# Como puedo Extraer datos desde la API de Siigo/para mostrarlos con lenguaje .NET

Tags: .net, post, asp.net-web-api, get, tokens

compañeros, tengo que hacer un proyecto en el que arrastre datos de una plataforma de facturación y más, tengo un proyecto .NET ASP CORE API Web, con el cual arrastro datos desde sql server, y los pinto con swagger, quisiera hacer lo mismo pero con la API de Siigo, esto para hacer métodos de get, post, put y delete

Cabe destacar que tengo datos como usuario de la siigo nube (usuario y contraseña)

y tengo un link de POST con sigo
a su vez tiene el username y un acces_key

La verdad no tengo idea de como hacerlo, agradezco si alguien me guia o me ayuda a desarrollar este proyecto, cualquier sugerencia o duda es bienvenida

Archivos que tengo
[image: Archivos que posee el proyecto actual]

Comment: ¿Dónde podemos encontrar la documentación de esa API?